# WP ALL IMPORT with foreach

Tags: woocommerce, wpallimport

I am trying to import products with **WP ALL IMPORT** to my shop. I am importing from **XML** where tree is like

```
<SHOPITEM>
  <ITEMNAME>
    ITEMNAME
  </ITEMNAME>
  ...
  <PARAMS>
    <PARAM>
       <PARAM_NAME>
       Name of parameter
      </PARAM_NAME>
      <VAL>
        Value of parameter
      </VAL>
    </PARAM>
  </PARAMS>
<PARAMS>
    <PARAM>
       <PARAM_NAME>
       Name of parameter
      </PARAM_NAME>
      <VAL>
        Value of parameter
      </VAL>
    </PARAM>
  </PARAMS>
<PARAMS>
    <PARAM>
       <PARAM_NAME>
       Name of parameter
      </PARAM_NAME>
      <VAL>
        Value of parameter
      </VAL>
    </PARAM>
  </PARAMS>
</SHOPITEM>
```

I need to create Attributes foreach of param_name and val
How should looks like code in these inputs? Right now I have this but it doesn't import them.

```
[FOREACH({PARAMS/PARAM})] {PARAM_NAME[1]} [ENDFOREACH]

[FOREACH({PARAMS/PARAM})] {VAL[1]} [ENDFOREACH]
```

[image]

Comment: you need to make each attribute name and value by adding separately.